# Git for Windows using Beyond Compare 4

Tags: git, beyondcompare4

I'm using **Windows 7** (don't tease; I really have no choice in the matter) and **Git for Windows**. I'm trying to get **Beyond Compare 4** to work as my diff and (eventually) my merge tool. I use Git from the command-line. The problem is I can't get Beyond Compare to launch when I do a diff. Things I've tried:

- `git diff MyChangedFile.txt`
- `git difftool MyChangedFile.txt`
- `git difftool --tool=bc MyChangedFile.txt`
- Changed the path to use `\\` instead of `/`. It doesn't seem to make a difference which is used.

After typing the command, there is a pause, and the command-prompt comes back, but nothing else happens. There is no error output, and Beyond Compare with my diff doesn't appear. I can enter the path to start Beyond Compare from the command-line and it opens, but I have to surround it with double-quotes:

```
"c:/Program Files/Beyond Compare 4/bcomp.exe"
```

I edited my .gitconfig file directly to add double-quotes, but I don't know if Git honors them.

I've followed the [instructions from Scooter Software](http://www.scootersoftware.com/support.php?zz=kb_vcs#gitwindows) and even tried the [manual instructions for GitHub](http://www.scootersoftware.com/support.php?zz=kb_vcs#githubwindows). We're not using GitHub, but another answer here on SO suggested it might work. Neither worked. I also tried most of the things suggested in [these SO posts](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=git%20beyond%20compare%20windows). Probably needless to say, none of them worked.

Details on my environment:

- Git: git version 2.15.1.windows.2 (64 bit)
- Windows: Windows 7 Enterprise, 64-bit, Service Pack 1
- Beyond Compare: Beyond Compare 4, 64-bit Edition, Version 4.2.3 (build 22587)

Pertinent configuration details:

```
[diff]
    tool = bc
[difftool "bc"]
    path = "c:/Program Files/Beyond Compare 4/bcomp.exe"
[core]
    editor = 'C:\\Program Files\\Notepad++\\notepad++.exe' -multiInst -notabbar -nosession -noPlugin
```

Anyone have any ideas on what I can try next? Need any further information?

Comment: I'm not completely certain it's still true, but I seem to remember I had to use the tool name as "bc3" rather than "bc4" or "bc".  Using "bc3" causes git to know how to pass the arguments correctly; otherwise you'll need to give git more help with specifying the right parameters.

Comment: According to Scooter's page, that's true for Git versions older than 2.2.0. For newer versions, they said to use `bc`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I guess this was a case of user error. I was trying to diff the files after they were staged. If I try to diff *before* I stage them, it works.

SMH...